# Images not showing up in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-templates

For some strange reason, images in my app in chrome and safari is not showing up but is in firefox.

If you copy and paste the image url into the browser it opens, but inside the html document, it is showing up as a broken image. Also tried on Ipad and does not show up either. The images are not hosted on our servers as they are just images curated from other sites.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Mabel/235553286541137?sk=app_238380339582506

Comment: From Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mabelslabels.com does not allow hotlinking from http://fansfave.com/

You can check with serverfault.com on the proper permissions to add to your web server, but I would assume that you need to either:

- Host the images on the same server, or
- Allow hotlinking

Answer (score 0):

It may be the cache problem. If u click a link(eg: allergy alert) that will open the image new tab. Then again relaod http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Mabel/235553286541137?sk=app_238380339582506
You can see the allergy alert image in the corresponding place. So try to check is there any cache problems.

Comment: don't think it is cache issue, think that the browser cache is what makes the image reappear the 2nd time. I think the problem is due to the refer url being blocked by the server hosting those images.